# Selenium RC Server opening for Junit

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, junit4

Is there a way we can start the Selenium RC server without using command prompt?

Also, is there a way of seeing the Log window and Test case window in the same one window?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code snippet:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
      {
      org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main();
      }
}, "SeleniumServer").start();
```

Or much simpler in Groovy:

```
new Thread({ org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(); }, "SeleniumServer").start()
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound a bit random, but I would suggest using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to control your build and test process. There is a nice plugin for [Selenium](http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/) in maven that will control the startup/shutdown of the server. Maven will provide you with many other added benefits.